# Plotting Lines in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in the following format:

Variable - Value
A          1
B          2
A          3
B          4

and so on.

Notice how the variable is recurring for different values. I want to draw a line for each variable that shows its different values assuming the X-axis is time.

Please any help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem...very little information seems to be shared...

Comment: The left column is the variable name and the right column is the variable value. Any variable has multiple entries with different values. Now i want to plot a line for each variable showing the different changes assuming the X-axis is time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start off by creating a Pivot table based on the data that you have and then create the line graph from there.